# Не работает VueRouter. Нужна помощь

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Все делал по шаблону из интернета, но router так и не работает как положено. При переходе по ссылке (*http://localhost:8080/track*), ничего не меняется. В DOM дереве на месте, куда должен был вставиться код из router, просто отображается пустой комментарий.  Консоль ошибок не выдает. Нужна помощь.

[image: введите сюда описание В DOM дереве на месте, куда должен был вставиться код из router, просто отображается пустой комментарий]

**App.vue**

```
<template>
```

```
<!-- HEADER -->
<Header />

<!-- CONTENT -->
<div class="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <!-- LEFT SITEBAR -->

      <!-- MAIN CONTAINER -->
        <!-- <Main 
        v-bind:music_arr="music_arr"
        /> -->
      <router-view></router-view>

      <!-- RIGHT SITEBAR -->

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- FOOTER -->
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

**router.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Track from './components/Track'

Vue.use(Router);

let router = new Router ({
    mode: 'history',
    router: [ 
        {
            path: '/track',
            component: Track
        }
    ]
})

export default router;
```

**Track.vue**

```
<template>
<div class="col-6">
    <div class="main-content">
        <div class="main main_padding">
            <h1>Треки</h1>
            <p class="description">Слушайте треки в хорошем качестве в жанре Eurodance и Euro Disco, скачивайте и делитесь в социальных сетях.</p>
        </div>
        <ul class="list_track">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Массив роутов должен называться routes, а у вас router